# Selenium Node API web driver wait timeout handler

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, timeout

I am new to Selenium web drive. Trying to do some page automation and are using `driver.wait` functions to wait for a selector rendering first and then do some operations later.

Was wondering if Selenium has a way to pass in a timeout handler to manage timeout if the element is not showing up after x seconds.

Here's my code:

```
driver.wait(function () {
    return driver.isElementPresent(webdriver.By.css('input[id="searchMap"]'));
}, 10000);
```

So after 10 secs if `input[id="searchMap"]` does not show up, Selenium script will end and Error is thrown.

I am looking for something like this:

```
driver.wait(function () {
    return driver.isElementPresent(webdriver.By.css('input[id="searchMap"]'));
}, 10000, function fail(){
    console.log("Time is up!");
});
```

Comment: Are you aware of the ExpectedConditions class?

Comment: Not seeing that on the javascript api doc

Comment: Are you talking about this:
http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/until_exports_Condition.html
?

Comment: You right, the api your using didn't port the ExpectedConditions class and so you dont have access to it.    Nightwatch.js has the closest thing that I have seen:  http://nightwatchjs.org/api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution myself. Have to use `catch` for Selenium `promise` class.

http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise_exports_Promise.html

Here is my code:

```
driver.wait(function () {
    return driver.isElementPresent(webdriver.By.css('div.info-page'));
}, 10000).catch(function(e){
    console.log('Catching Error');
});
```